# I need to query an array of data embedded in a dataset to determine if a value exist

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry, but I can't provide actual code, so this maybe be difficult to understand.

I'll do the best I can.

```
**dset.data.arrayofData** // format of my issue

I can **GetAll from my dset** which is necessary.
```

The x =>   would equal data returned.

```
The problem is **data.arrayofData** is an array of data.
```

I need to determine if a value exist anywhere in this array for each record to determine its worth to me.

This arrayOfData would be similar to.

```
**arrayOfData
{
    FirstName,
    LastName, 
    Email,
}**

Let's say I'm logged in and identified by my email address. **LoggedInEmail**.
```

I need to search the array of this record to determine if my email address is present and the array can be 1, 2, 3, etc... in size.

```
**arrayOfData[0]
arrayOfData[1]
arrayOfData[2]
arrayOfData[~]**

What would I use to determine if my **LoggedInEmail** is present in **arrayOfData**?

**GetAll( x=> x.arrayOfData...)** and then what?  Select? Any? Contains?
```

Sorry, but this is all I can provide.  My hands are tied on that end.

Sorry about the formatting.  I haven't been here in years.

I've reviewed some other questions, but they don't appear to apply here.

Comment: Without posting your actual code, you should be able to create a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just because your employer will not allow you to copy/paste their code into a Stackoverflow window doesn't mean you can't show any code.  Take your weird pseudo code (what does `dset.data.arrayofData` mean - jeez, what does `dset` mean) and translate it into a simple example in C#.  Read up on what a [mcve] is.

Comment: providing more real code would mean rewriting the code because it can't be shared.

Comment: @TimSchmelter
providing more real code would mean rewriting the code because it can't be shared.  I gave an example of the array in the example as close to real code as it gets.  DataSet is what I've pulled in from a repository.    For example. 

var  whatever = definitionOfRepository.GetRepository<T>().GetAll( ) ;  
The code to query goes inside the "GetAll()".

I will check out your suggestion.   Get all will apply to what is in the dset and the code inside filters what you want to return.

Comment: @Flydog57   Thanks.  I know what about minimal reproducible examples.  I've had to work without it for years.      If you can't help it is no problem.  I just thought I would ask.
Some have provided some nice suggestions with what I provided.    
Sometimes a little suggestion can give enough of an idea towards the solution.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a clue what you are talking about.  Is the `dset` in your `** Explanation ***` the _"dataset"_ in the title of the question?  Is that a `System.Data.Dataset` dataset?  If so, where does the array come in?  ADO.NET datasets have rows and columns - I don't believe there are any arrays in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var arrayWithData = new List<string> 
{
    "FirstName",
    "LastName",
    "Email"
};

var isInList = arrayWithData.Any(a => a.Equals("Email"));
```

With Any you can use a lambda to compare the value in the array to the value you are searching for. It will stop iterating when the condition is true. If the value is not in the list, then it will compare each value in the entire list to the value you give in the lambda and return false in the end because the condition was not true anywhere.

Comment: I'll try it out and get back to you.  I've seen too uses of ANY and I was wondering how far I could use it.     This may help. Ill let you know.